# Flaticon CSS: change size of one icon, not all

Tags: css

I am working with flaticon icons, from https://www.flaticon.com

I am trying to resize one of the icons and keep others with same size. I can change the font-size in "flaticon.css" but all the icons change their size.

Is it possible to change the font-size of just one icon?

flaticon.css:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("./Flaticon.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("./Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("./Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
  font-family: Flaticon;
        font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.flaticon-can:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon-interface:before { content: "\f101"; }
.flaticon-healthcare:before { content: "\f102"; }
.flaticon-kitchen:before { content: "\f103"; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just add a `font-size` rule to the specific item you want to change. I’d recommend doing this in your own style sheet rather than modifying flaticon.css, but either way will work.

```css
.flaticon-healthcare::before {
  content: "\f102";
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Comment: First line is ".flaticon-circle-with-an-arrow-pointing-to-left::before", with double two points. Actually working